# Objective-C code explaination

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone help explain why I can't have an else if following an if? The error is saying expected expression but I don't know what it means by that

// Declaring variables as integers
        int account, depAmount, withAmount;

```
    Account *Account1=[[Account alloc] init];

    // Prompt user to input account number
    NSLog(@"Please input your account number here: ");
    scanf("%i", &account); // Accept user input

    if (account==1000)
        NSLog(@"How much do you want to deposit: ");
        scanf("%i", &depAmount);

        [Account1 setaccountNumber: account];
        [Account1 setbegBalance: 900.50];
        [Account1 addDeposit: depAmount];

        NSLog(@"How much do you want to withdrawl: ");
        scanf("%i", &withAmount);
        [Account1 setnewbegBalance: 900.50 + depAmount];
        [Account1 subtractWithdrawal: withAmount];

    NSLog(@"Your account number is: %i\nBeginning balance: %f\nNew balance is: %f", [Account1 accountNumber], [Account1 begBalance], [Account1 newBalance]);

    else if (account==2000)
        NSLog(@"How much do you want to deposit: ");
        scanf("%i", &depAmount);

        [Account1 setaccountNumber: account];
        [Account1 setbegBalance: 700.75];
        [Account1 addDeposit: depAmount];

        NSLog(@"Your account number is: %i\nBeginning balance: %f\nNew balance is: %f", [Account1 accountNumber], [Account1 begBalance], [Account1 newBalance]);

    else if (account==3000)
        NSLog(@"How much do you want to deposit: ");
        scanf("%i", &depAmount);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need curly braces for the instructions you want executed as part of the if condition. If you don't have curly braces, only the 1 statement following the if statement will be executed. So add curly braces like this one:

```
if (account==1000)
{
    NSLog(@"How much do you want to deposit: ");
    scanf("%i", &depAmount);

    [Account1 setaccountNumber: account];
    [Account1 setbegBalance: 900.50];
    [Account1 addDeposit: depAmount];

    NSLog(@"How much do you want to withdrawl: ");
    scanf("%i", &withAmount);
    [Account1 setnewbegBalance: 900.50 + depAmount];
    [Account1 subtractWithdrawal: withAmount];

NSLog(@"Your account number is: %i\nBeginning balance: %f\nNew balance is: %f", [Account1 accountNumber], [Account1 begBalance], [Account1 newBalance]);
}
```

Comment: Oh but the textbook didn't have curly braces after the if. I'm doing a project and was following the book, which is why I spent like an hour trying to figure out why it wouldn't let me include an else if

Comment: Glad we helped. Which book is this? You might want to file an errata with the publisher!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing curly braces around the block of `if`. When you have multiple statements in a block, you *must* put curly braces around all statements. Unlike some other programming languages such as Python, the indentation in Objective C is insignificant. All grouping of statements in related blocks is done by curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Between an `if` and `else` there should be only a one statement.

Your **`one statement` can be

A.) A single statement e.g. `a = b;`
B.) Multiple statements grouped in a block.

```
{
    a = b;
    b = 20;
}
```